# Молодцы - что за конструкция ("Хорошая новость, молодцы!")?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

> Хорошая новость, молодцы!

Молодцы - это неполное предложение или постпозитивный номинатив?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Хорошая новость, молодцы!**

Я думаю, что это постпозитивные номинативы со значением оценки, так как они тесно связаны с предшествующим сообщением.

https://studfiles.net/preview/2682296/

Другие постпозитивные номинативы в смысловом отношении более тесно связаны **с предшествующим сообщением,** а в **грамматическом** — с номинативным бессказуемно-подлежащным или **неполным** предложением.

Однако функционирование его только **в составе синтаксического целого (совместно с предшествующим предложением)** допускает толкование его как конструкции непредложенческого характера.

Значения именительного могут быть самыми разнообразными.

Номинатив в постпозиции может заключать в себе **значение оценки**: Есть письмо. На листке — торопливые строки: «Если можешь — прости. Так случилось. Ушла». Равнодушные строки. Слова ледяные (Лис.);

Comment: Спасибо. Хорошая новость - неполное предложение? Может ли здесь подразумеваться местоимение это?

Comment: Вообще-то я считаю, что это два постпозитивных номинатива со значением оценки. Если считать их неполными предложениями, то это выглядит так: (Это) хорошая новость, (вы) молодцы. Но  есть возможность полностью отнести эту конструкцию к номинативам.

Comment: Может ли ответ начинаться с постпозитивного номинатива?

Comment: Ответ, наверное, не может, так как перед номинативом должен быть тест, например: Значит, у них всё в порядке. Хорошая новость, молодцы! А если текста нет, то тогда это неполные предложения.